# adjust table to fit the page (code from tablesgenerator.com)

Tags: tables, page, fit

I am creating a table with 5 columns and ~40 rows using the tablesgenerator website:

[image]

I get the following LaTeX code:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{lscape}
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllll}
\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
\hline
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx} &  &  &  &  \\
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30th June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30th June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30th June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx} &  &  &  &  \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Month & 30th June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\
\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx} &  &  &  &  \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Month & 1st July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Month & 1st July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30th June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Month & 1st July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Month & 1st July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30th June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30th June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

However, this is the result in my document:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to adjust the table so that it fits within the page while allowing for the margins of the document?

Also, does anyone know how to remove the bold from the caption in the 2nd page and changed it to have the same caption but with Continued like this "xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)"

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath {{./Sect1-Figures/} {./Sect2-Figures/}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

**Edit**
My code based on code from @Mico:

```
\begin{landscape}

%\begin{sidewaystable}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont
\small


%\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}
\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} LlllL @{}} % automatic line-breaking in cols 1 and 5

\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}%
{\normalsize{\textbf{Table \thetable:} xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)}} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\

\addlinespace 
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ 
%\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

%\end{sidewaystable}
```

I get:

[image]

**Q1:** How could I move caption from 2nd page onwards to the centre of the page?

**Q2:** I cannot have landscape pages since I will need to print this document. If I replace `landscape` with `sidewaystable` I get the below. Do you know how to overcome this?

[image]

Comment: What is your documentclass? You can use `tabularray` or use `p`/`X` column type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just added those details to my answer. It's \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

Comment: Off-topic: Since you use the `setspace` package, you should definitely not be running `\linespread{1.5}`. Instead, please run `\setstretch{1.5}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main recommendations would be that you (a) switch from a `longtable` to an `xltabular` environment and (b) enable automatic line breaking in columns 1 and 5. Enabling automatic hanging indentation in columns 1 and 5 would add a nice touch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular} % instead of 'longtable'
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules (instead of \hline)
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight} % save value of '\textheight' param.

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} LlllL @{}} % automatic line-breaking in cols 1 and 5

\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}%
{Table \thetable, continued from previous page} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\

\addlinespace 
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ 
%\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions, marked as "Q1" and "Q2".

> Q1: How could I move caption from 2nd page onwards to the centre of the page?

In the `\endhead` group, please change `\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}` to `\multicolumn{5}{c}`.

> Q2: I cannot have landscape pages since I will need to print this document. If I replace landscape with sidewaystable I get the below. Do you know how to overcome this?

The landscape-format pages will be printed properly automatically. You needn't do anything special. The fact that they're displayed *on screen* in, well, landscape format in no way affects how they'll be printed on paper.

Comment: Many thanks Micro for your suggestion. Two things: 1) It changes the page to horizontal, instead of rotating the table and keeping page vertical as per the pictures in my question. I've tried \begin{sidewaystable} instead of \being{landscape} but as a result, the table does not fit the page again. Do you know how to overcome this? 2) Do you know how to remove the bold from the caption in the 2nd page and changed it to have the same caption but with Continued like this "xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)"? I've added my preamble to my question.

Comment: @Daniela - Not sure I understand your first comment: The table *is* typeset in "landscape" format. If you want to remove the **bold-facing** from the header cells from the second page onward, just remove all five `\textbf{...}` wrappers in the `\endhead` group of instructions. Oh, and my name is "Mico", not "Micro"...

Comment: I am sorry, Mico. I have now gone very carefully through your code and I have edited my question with the output I get based on your code (under Edit). I only have 2 small problems, I have included them in my question (under Edit).

Comment: @Daniela - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico. All works. I marked the question as correct. If you have time, do you know why the space between caption and table in page 1 is bigger than the space between caption and table in subsequent pages? It would be perfect if the space was exactly the same.

Comment: Just fyi - I posted a new question about creating a footnote for this table: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681199/how-to-add-footnote-to-table-created-using-xltabular

Comment: @Daniela - To replicate the vertical separation present between the caption and `\toprule` on the first page, I suggest you change `...from previous page} \\[0.5ex]` in the `\endhead` group to `...from previous page} \\ \addlinespace[14.4pt]` (if the main document font size is `12pt`).

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Mico do you have time for one last question on this? I am creating a table using this code - how can I make sure column #1 is as wide as the longest text and columns #2, #3, #4 and #5 are exactly of the same width? If you have time, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227920/specify-same-width-for-certain-columns-using-xltabular

Comment: @Daniela - Done. :-)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you, Mico!

Comment: Mico, sorry can I ask one last thing about this particular question. I noticed that using the code above if I have a long title the table goes over the right margin. The problem is not on the 1st but subsequent pages e.g. {Table \thetable, continued from previous page xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx} \\[0.5ex] do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Daniela - I'm not sure why you would even write `{Table \thetable, continued from previous page xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx}`. Please don't torture your readers with long captions. Captions -- and especially continuation captions -- simply aren't the right place to tuck away lots of information. Ideally, captions are short and snappy. However, if you simply can't help yourself and *insist* on providing captions that are longer than `\textwidth`, I suggest you replace `\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}` with `\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `longtable` I rather would use`tabularay` package. It provide among other features simple code for writing long tables ...

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tabularray} % instead of 'longtable'
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1][0pt]{%
        \SetRow{abovesep+=#1}
        \SetCell[c=4]{l, font=\small\itshape\bfseries}
                                  }
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
                            
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx},
  label = {tab:my-table}
                ]{colspec = {@{} X[l, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                      cmd=\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em]
                                 ll
                                 X[0.5, l] 
                                 X[l, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                      cmd=\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em] 
                             @{}},
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                  row{2}  = {belowsep=0.5pt},
                  row{3-Y} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{even[4]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                  rowhead = 1} 
    \toprule
xxxxxxxxx   & xxxx xxxxx    & xxxx xxxxxx   & xxxx xxxx xxxxx  & xxxxxx    \\
    \midrule
%% body of table
\subtitle  xxxxxxxxxxxx
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
%%%%
\subtitle[5pt]  xxxxxxxxxxxx
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\
%%%%
\subtitle[5pt]  xxxxxxxxxxxx    
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation 
            & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx 
            & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x 
            & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx 
            & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx 
            & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]