# How to add footnote to table created using xltabular

Tags: tables, xltabular

I have the following code to create a table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\graphicspath {{./sect1-Figures/} {./sect2-Figures/}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    
    \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont
    \small
    
    \begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} LlllL @{}} % automatic line-breaking in cols 1 and 5
    
    \caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
    \label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\normalsize{\textbf{Table \thetable:} xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)}} \\[0.5ex]
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    %% body of table
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
    xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    
    \addlinespace 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
    Avg xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & official statistics\_1* \\
    \# xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & official statistics\_2‡ \\
    \% xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & official statistics\_3§ \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Q:** How can I create a footnote at the bottom of this table on the left side that includes:

*Note:*

Avg = Average; # = number of; % = percentage

`*` https://www.google.com

‡ https://www.youtube.com

§ https://www.wikipedia.org

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I have a compilable test file above including class and necessary packages.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry! For some reason I did not see the first part of your code - maybe I accidentality scrolled the code down while opening the page.

Comment: This can be simply done with using `longtblr` of `tabularray` package ... just add `remark{Note} = {desired text}` in the table option (after caption, see my answer on your previous question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on a suggestion made by @Zarko, I'd like to suggest that you replace

```
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
```

with

```
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\mylen}@{}}{\footnotesize%
   Avg = Average; \# = number of; \% = percentage.}\\
\endlastfoot
```

Upon recompiling your code, the last few lines on the table's final page should look like this:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
%\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont
%\small
\setstretch{1} % better than "\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}"
    
\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} LlllL @{}} % automatic line-breaking in cols 1 and 5
    
    \caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
    \label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\normalsize{\textbf{Table \thetable:} xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)}} \\
    \addlinespace[12pt]
    \toprule
    \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\mylen}@{}}{\footnotesize%
       Avg = Average; \# = number of; \% = percentage.}\\
    \endlastfoot
    
    %% body of table
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
    xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    
    \addlinespace 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
    Avg xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & official statistics\_1* \\
    \# xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & official statistics\_2‡ \\
    \% xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & official statistics\_3§ \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico, it works. One thing left: do you know how I could replicate the exact structure I tried to display in my question: "Note:" in one line, and then below those 3 elements (Avg = Average; \# = number of; \% = percentage), and then one link per line?

Comment: @Daniela - have you tried providing four separate `\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize ... }` directives?

Comment: Of course, thanks - all works now!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my answer on your previous question. As I noted in my comment, to it you only need to add

```
remark{Note} = {Avg = Average; \# = number of; \% = percentage}
```

after `label = {...}` in table preamble.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tabularray} % instead of 'longtable'
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1][0pt]{%
        \SetRow{abovesep+=#1}
        \SetCell[c=4]{l, font=\small\itshape\bfseries}
                                  }
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
                            
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx},
  label = {tab:my-table},
remark{Note} = {Avg = Average; \# = number of; \% = percentage}  % <--- added for table note
                ]{colspec = {@{} X[l, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                      cmd=\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em]
                                 ll
                                 X[0.5, l] 
                                 X[l, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                      cmd=\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em] 
                             @{}},
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                  row{2}  = {belowsep=0.5pt},
                  row{3-Y} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{even[4]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                  rowhead = 1} 
    \toprule
xxxxxxxxx   & xxxx xxxxx    & xxxx xxxxxx   & xxxx xxxx xxxxx  & xxxxxx    \\
    \midrule
%% body of table
\subtitle  xxxxxxxxxxxx
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Individual    & Day           & 30 June 2000  & xxxxx     \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
%%%%
\subtitle[5pt]  xxxxxxxxxxxx
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\
%%%%
\subtitle[5pt]  xxxxxxxxxxxx    
            &               &               &               &           \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation 
            & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx 
            & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x 
            & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
            & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx 
            & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx 
            & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx 
            & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Zarko. I am using xltabular package though to create the table, and now I just need to understand how I could add a footnote to that. Do you know how to add footnotes in a table created with xltabular?

Comment: @Daniela, I know. But you may reconsider if your selecting of the `xltabular` way for table is the best way to go. Comparison of codes show, that `code`using `tabularray` is shorter, for final result you need only one compilation, etc.  Of course, you can extend `xltabular` table with `threeparttable` package or simple on the end add `\multicolumn` cell where you write your nodes.